# Installing kali linux on lenovo in free dos

Tags: kali-linux, freedos

So, I have downloaded kali linux image file from the kali official website, and I have burnt the .ISO image file to my pendrive, and before installing i changed the boot priority order, I also selected usb boot from boot option, nothing happened, I cant get past this free dos screen, no matter what, I simply can't install kali linux, whatever I try, I can't get past this screen
[free dos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Keh4w.jpg) 
and moreover this a new laptop with a pre-installed free dos, and I am not attempting a dual boot. 
my laptop specifications: 
lenovo ideapad 300 
intel core i5 
amd radeoen graphics

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that your system type is UEFI which doesn't recognize bootable device if there are no EFI files in the disk image. First check your bootable USB if there is a directory name /EFI/BOOT/`.efi extension files`.

If there is none then You have to manually create a folder in your bootable USB as /EFI/BOOT/`paste efi files here`. *Folder name is case sensitive*.

Download all EFI files from [here](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/fedora/releases/18/Fedora/x86_64/os/EFI/BOOT/) and copy them to that folder.

Which model you are using?